# Apache SSLVerifyClient minimum depth

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I have the following scenario: A central update server (running apache) is hosting update packages for different customers. Some of the packages contain license information, so customer A mustn't be able to access packages of customer B.

I want to ensure this by using client certificates. So I created a root CA (using plain openssl) and created two intermediate CA (one per customer, both directly signed by the root CA, so those are in "parallel").

I was able to configure apache in a way it requires the clients to provide a valid certificate. Unfortunately, both vHosts on the server accept certificates issued by both intermediate CAs.

How can I configure apache so it only accepts client certificates issued directly by one of both intermediate CAs?

This is one of the configuration files:

```
#pache  ************************************
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost cust2.munki.puppet.intra:443>
ServerName cust2.munki.puppet.intra

## Vhost docroot
DocumentRoot "/srv/munki/cust2.munki.puppet.intra"

## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /srv/munki/cust2.munki.puppet.intra

<Directory "/srv/munki/cust2.munki.puppet.intra">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

## Logging
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/munki.puppet.intra cust2 ssl_error_ssl.log"
ServerSignature Off
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/munki.puppet.intra cust2 ssl_access_ssl.log" combined

## SSL directives
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      "/etc/ssl/cust2.munki.puppet.intra.cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/etc/ssl/private/cust2.munki.puppet.intra.key.pem"
SSLVerifyClient         require
SSLVerifyDepth          2
SSLCACertificateFile    "/etc/ssl/cust2.cert.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

regards, christian

Comment: Have you tried using in Apache configuration each intermediate CA certificate as the "root" CA used by Apache for each virtual host? Otherwise see this part: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire and all defined environment variables shown at top of page, especially SSL_CLIENT_I_DN in your case.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Thanks for the inspiration. I ended up waiving the chain and just creating a new root for every customer. In my special case, there is no downside to this and it's easier than sslrequire (also: sslrequire seems to be deprecated)